# python and javascript: how to download a file from Flask server

Tags: javascript, python, server

I want to create a web page so that users can download file from my computer, which is the server.

I'm asking this question because I can't really find an answer on the Internet. What I found was about how to download files using python. Just to clarify: I want a web page which users can download files stored on the server (my computer). I'm not sure if this requires python and javascript working together or not.

Answer (score 0):

I know Python, so that's what I'll recommend. If you use the [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) framework, you can serve a local file with a quick snippet like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/files/example.txt">Download example.txt</a>'

@app.route('/files/<path:filename>', methods=['GET'])
def download_file(filename):
    proj_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(proj_dir, 'files_dir'),
        filename=filename)
```

*files_dir* is a subfolder within the project directory and contains any files you want to serve for download, including *example.txt* in this exmaple.

If you navigate to localhost or http://yourserver.com/ it will display a link that downloads the *example.txt* file.